# how to create a dll of my c++ code.

Tags: c++, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how dll created out of c++ source and how it is used in other sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289397/how-dll-created-out-of-c-source-and-how-it-is-used-in-other-sources)

I need to call a c++ code, which get the PID/VID of the external device in my java code. I googled and some info. By converting the c++ code to a dll, I can use it in my java code. Any suggestion to how to convert my c++ code to a dll file.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289397/how-dll-created-out-of-c-source-and-how-it-is-used-in-other-sources) covers similar ground and does the same as I would do: tell you to Google for one of the tons of tutorials out there that explain this.

Comment: I need to create a dll without using visual studio. Thats why I neglect that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is JNI (Java Native Interface).

Here is a link for compiling a dll using VC++ - http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/07/java-native-interface-jni-example-using.html

and one using MinGW - http://www.mingw.org/node/41

Answer (score 1):

Find step by step process to make dll with VC++ [here](http://logix4u.net/Programming/vc++/A_Tutorial_on_creating_DLLs_with_VC++.html).

Also you need to use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) for using c++ dll into your java project.